# Sorting Core Data by date typed as NSString

Tags: iphone, core-data, nsstring, nsdate

I get a bunch of dates from a server in YYYY-MM-DD NSString format which we immediately stick into core data for accessing. However, I need to do a sorted fetch request with a greater than date predicate. How can I say "date greater than X" when date is a string instead of a date object?

AKA, start below is NSString, not NSDate

```
 NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(start <= %@) AND (name == %@)", currentTime, name];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of storing the dates as strings, and then having to sort the strings, parse the dates with an NSDateFormatter, then store them as NSDates in core data, then you can do all sorts of predicates with them with relative ease.

Comment: There are well over 500k dates in our data object, I'd rather not take all of them out of core data, type them with NSDateFormatter and restore them. It's a last resort.

Comment: @Eric I agree with Jesse Crocker. You should store the dates as NSDate in a coredata database. If you have over 500K dates, make a quick script to convert the dates (Mac Foundation Application) by first loading your old database, pulling out each individual object, using a NSDateFormatter to convert the string into a date and then storing this in a new database.

Comment: We tried for 24 hours and couldn't find a better alternative, thanks for the help!